# on checkbox click showCount get's selected for all items in angular 8

Tags: javascript, angular

I am trying to achieve the change event to a single item, to get the count. when I click on the single checkbox `showCount` is getting true for all the items,

Is there any way, to get this condition true for selected checkbox only

```
<div *ngFor="let a of data">
<label>
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" (change)="onCheck($event)">
{{a.name}}
</label>
<span *ngIf="showCount">{{a.count}}</span>
</div>
```

.ts file

```
showCount:boolean = false;

data = [
{"name": "javascript" , "count" : 12},
{"name": "Angular" , "count" : 13},
{"name": "Typescript" , "count" : 14},
{"name": "Java" , "count" : 15},
{"name": "Python" , "count" : 16},
]
onCheck(event){
if(event.target.checked){
 this.showCount = true;
}
  else{
    this.showCount= false;
}  

}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Angular2:Checkbox with \*ngFor in a table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42751210/angular2checkbox-with-ngfor-in-a-table)

Comment: @R.Richards my scenario is --- when I check the first checkbox ----showCount is getting true for every item

Comment: And, as shown in nearly all the answers in the post I linked, the checkbox needs to have a unique name for each one that gets created in the `ngFor` loop. This isn't the first time someone has run across this issue.

Comment: @R.Richards I am in the learning stage.. I got your point, but after having a unique name I am still getting the same issue---on one checkbox click, my condition gets true for all other items

Comment: post generated html

Answer (score 0):

You need a way to differentiate each of the checkboxes

```
<div *ngFor="let a of data; let i = index">
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" (change)="onCheck($event, i)">
      {{a.name}}
  </label>
  <span *ngIf="showCount[i]">{{a.count}}</span>
</div>
```

```
showCount:boolean[] = [false];
onCheck(event, i){
 if(event.target.checked){
   this.showCount[i] = true;
  }
  else{
    this.showCount[i] = false;
  }  
}
```